# Stuck on ilclient_get_input_buffer

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, openmax

My program is currently getting stuck on this call: ilclient_get_input_buffer(). Unfortunately due to the lack of documentation on openmax IL I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
if(ilclient_create_component(decoder->Client, &decoder->Video_Decode, "video_decode", ILCLIENT_CREATE_FLAGS_T(ILCLIENT_DISABLE_ALL_PORTS | ILCLIENT_ENABLE_INPUT_BUFFERS)) != 0) {
    return;
  }

set_tunnel(decoder->Tunnel,     decoder->Video_Decode,    131, decoder->Video_Render, 10);

ilclient_change_component_state(decoder->Video_Decode, OMX_StateExecuting);

if (OMX_SetParameter(ILC_GET_HANDLE(decoder->Video_Decode), OMX_IndexParamVideoPortFormat, &decoder->Format) == OMX_ErrorNone &&
        ilclient_enable_port_buffers(decoder->Video_Decode, 130, NULL, NULL, NULL) == 0) {
     ilclient_change_component_state(decoder->Video_Decode, OMX_StateExecuting);
  }

decoder->Buffer = ilclient_get_input_buffer(decoder->Video_Decode, 130, 1);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [If `block` non-zero, the function will block until a buffer is available.](https://github.com/adafruit/pi_hello_video/blob/master/libs/ilclient/ilclient.h#L756)

Comment: how can I get it to return a buffer then? I can't do anything if it doesn't allocate a buffer for me. I am pretty sure I initialized it incorrectly